# Items being returned out of order after mapping with a promise - Ionic/Angular/Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, ionic-framework

I am retrieving items from a database for a feed, and they need to stay in the order that I retrieve them (because it's a feed). Right now, I take the array from the query and map it. After all is said and done - it will display the feed objects out of order. Here is my code:

```
    let cacheKey = 'promos';
    let promises_array:Array<any> = [];
    let mapped;
    this.cache.removeItem(cacheKey);

    this.cache.getItem(cacheKey).catch(() => {
      let store = [];

      this.list2 = this.af.list('/promos', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 10
      }});

      this.subscription4 = this.list2.subscribe(items => {
        mapped = items.map((item) => {
          return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('/settings/' + item.customMetadata.username + '/profilepicture.png');

            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
              console.log(url + "in download url !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
              item.customMetadata.picURL = url;
              store.push(item.customMetadata);
              resolve();
            }).catch((e) => {
              console.log("in caught url !!!!!!!$$$$$$$!!");
              item.customMetadata.picURL = 'assets/blankprof.png';
              store.push(item.customMetadata);
              resolve();
            });


          })
        })

        console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped) + "    mappped things");



        this.startAtKey = items[0].$key;
        this.lastKey = this.startAtKey;

        let results = Promise.all(mapped);
        results.then(() => {
        //setTimeout(() => {

          this.items = store.reverse();
          //this.classesListArray.reverse();   
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.items) + " value value vlaue items");
          return this.cache.saveItem(cacheKey, this.items);
        //}, 3000);

        })
      })
    }).then(data => {
      this.items = data;
    })
```

Im guessing that the images are being loaded at different rates each time, and are being mapped out of order somehow due to their loading time, even though map is supposed to preserve order with an array. The other thing is, I'm not sure if what is coming back from the request is actually an array. When I log `typeof items` inside the subscript, it returns `object`, but with `JSON.stringify` it shows an array structure - could this be why it is losing order? It is not actually an array?

Answer (score 0):

Just order the items after you have them all.

```
store.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.prop - b.prop;
});
```